# cuda multiple memory access

Tags: gpgpu, cuda

Please give me some explanation how a memory access works in the following kernel:

```
__global__ void kernel(float4 *a)
{
     int tid = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

     float4 reg1, reg2;
     reg1 = a[tid]; //each thread reads a unique memory location

     for(int i = 0; i < totalThreadsNumber; i++)
     {  
          reg2 = a[i]; //all running threads start reading 
                       //the same global memory location
          //some computations
     }

     for(int i = 0; i < totalThreadsNumber; i++)
     {
          a[i] = reg1; // all running threads start writing 
                       //to the same global memory location
                       //race condition
     }
}
```

How does it work in the first loop ? Is there some serialization ? I assume that the second loop causes threads serialization (only within a warp ?) and the result is undefined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping my explanation to Fermi (sm_2x), on older hardware memory access are per half-warp instead.

In the first loop (reading) the whole warp is reading from the same address into a local variable. This results in a "broadcast". Since Fermi has a L1 cache either one cache line will be loaded or the data will be fetched directly from the cache (for subsequent  iterations). In other words, there is no serialisation.

In the second loop (writing) which thread wins is undefined - just like any multi-threaded programming model if multiple threads write to the same location the programmer is responsible for understanding the race conditions. You have no control over which warp in the block will execute last and also no control over which thread within the last warp will complete the write, so you can't predict what the final value will be.

Comment: When a few warps running at the same time on the SM on older architecture a memory access looks like this ?: first warp (half-warp broadcast | serialization | half-warp broadcast), |serialization?| second warp (half-warp broadcast | serialization | half-warp broadcast) etc. Is there serialization also between warps which running simultaneously or only within a warp ?

Comment: I don't really follow your comment, sorry! I'll try to help... In my mind serialisation implies that the operations execute in-order which is not the case, you cannot predict which warp will execute the instruction first. There is no "serialisation" between warps (although you can synchronise with `__syncthreads()`). Having said that, only one half warp (on sm_1x hardware) can be issuing memory operations at any given cycle, perhaps that is what you mean?

Comment: So many warps reside on SM and are ready for an execution but only a half warp(sm_1x) or a warp(sm_2x) can run at a given time. Warps execution works like a context switching !?

Comment: I don't think so. For SM_2x, there are 16 Ld/st units, so for memory operations, there is only a half warp can execute (therefore takes 2 cycles to issue). Warps execution is described as context switching, but actually it is not, it is just about to choose which warp to execute next (NVIDIA says it is zero-overhead context switching, but I don't really think so).